Nested JSON files in python to CSV file
i have used my script to pull API Data (thanks to those who helped)
next stage of my problem... the JSON file came back like below
[
        {
            "team": {
                "division": "divison1",
                "rank": 1,
                "team_name": "team name 1",
                "team_id": "82f9a58f",
                "value": 1450,
                "score": 2417,
                "w/d/l": "35/10/6"
            },
            "coach": {
                "coach_name": "coach a",
                "coach_id": "4364b994",
                "lang": "english",
                "country": null
            }
        },

[in a csv the data looks like this]
(https://i.sstatic.net/AEmwua8J.png)
i now need to get this into .csv with the formatting below.
division,rank,team_name,team_id,value,score,w/d/l,coach_name,coach_id,lang,country
division1,1,team name 1,82f9a58f,1450,2417,35/10/6,coach a,4364b994,english,null
anyone know how i can do this? have had a search around and cant find anything that has worked so far
searched around but to no avail

Is your question about how to merge those sub-dictionaries together on a row by row basis, or is your question about how to write a list of dictionaries to a csv file?

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data. CSV is a pure text format; you'd include it inside code fences directly in the question, just like the code.

To convert your JSON data to a CSV file with the desired format, you can use Python. The pandas library is particularly useful for this kind of data manipulation. Here’s a script that accomplishes this task:
import json
import pandas as pd

# Sample JSON data
json_data = '''
[
    {
        "team": {
            "division": "division1",
            "rank": 1,
            "team_name": "team name 1",
            "team_id": "82f9a58f",
            "value": 1450,
            "score": 2417,
            "w/d/l": "35/10/6"
        },
        "coach": {
            "coach_name": "coach a",
            "coach_id": "4364b994",
            "lang": "english",
            "country": null
        }
    }
]
'''

# Load JSON data
data = json.loads(json_data)

# Normalize the JSON data into a flat table
team_data = pd.json_normalize(data)

# Create a DataFrame with the desired columns
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'division': team_data['team.division'],
    'rank': team_data['team.rank'],
    'team_name': team_data['team.team_name'],
    'team_id': team_data['team.team_id'],
    'value': team_data['team.value'],
    'score': team_data['team.score'],
    'w/d/l': team_data['team.w/d/l'],
    'coach_name': team_data['coach.coach_name'],
    'coach_id': team_data['coach.coach_id'],
    'lang': team_data['coach.lang'],
    'country': team_data['coach.country']
})

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

print(df)


Pandas is a great tool, but is really overkill here...
